# Understanding Gunicorn and Flask on Docker/Docker-Compose

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

I'm having trouble getting Flask and Gunicorn to work properly on Docker using Docker-compose

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Kyle Calica "Kyle Calica"
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev  build-essential python-pip gunicorn
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install ez_setup
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r ./app/requirements.txt
CMD [ "gunicorn", "-b", ":8000", "run" ]
```

Docker-Compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
 web:
  build: .
  volumes:
  - ./:/var/www/crypto
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
```

run.py:

```
from app import app
app.run()
```

From my understanding the Gunicorn master will run at port 8000 on all interfaces in the **container**

And then it'll spawn a node to run at port 5000 in the **container** at 127.0.0.1/localhost.

From there I link port 5000 in the `container` to my `host`port `8000`

I expected to see my application from my host computer at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`
instead nothing happened and nothing seemed to be connecting.

I have done this before but can't remember what I did differently.

`(env) paper-street:CoinSlack kyle$ gunicorn -b :8000 run
[2017-09-16 17:43:59 -0700] [15402] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-09-16 17:43:59 -0700] [15402] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (15402)
[2017-09-16 17:43:59 -0700] [15402] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-09-16 17:43:59 -0700] [15405] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15405
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

^the reason why is because it seems like it spawned a worker and is running it at port 5000, i can't access my app through port 8000

Comment: 1. Why would it spawn a node at port 5000? 2. You link 5000 to 5000, not to 8000. 3. Try changing ports to 8000:8000 in your yml file, that should do it.

Comment: ill post the output of `gunicorn -b :8000 run` to show why i believe it to spawn at 500. and i'll try that.

Comment: Also trying execing into the container and running `curl localhost:8000` and `curl localhost:5000` to see what's happening in there.

Comment: @AlexHall posted some output to show that it has a worker with an instance of my app at port 5000. nope it just hangs if i try to access it from the gunicorn port and not the worker port

Comment: Try to specify the port like this ` - "5000:8000"` . Are you sure the last line of your log is not a hardcoded message?

Comment: yes my application really just returns 'hello' at index. I can post that code if you want but i think it's highly unneeded.

Comment: @AlexHall it returns `hello` which is expected at `localhost:5000` but hangs at `localhost:8000` which would be the gunicorn instance... this is from the `gunicorn -b :8000 run` command

Comment: I don't think `app.run()` should be there. It's up to gunicorn to run the app, not Flask.

Comment: wait then what do i run to run my application????? im confused. i used run.py as my entrypoint. I've done this before but my flask structure was different. i've never seen it without an `app.run()` before.

Comment: whoa learned i can just run the "directory" as a module! never knew i can do that, i saw some structures using a `run.py` guess for some reason mines can't do that?

Comment: got it to work! changed it to `CMD [ "gunicorn", "-b", ":8000", "app:app" ]` so that gunicorn runs it, i think i kinda get it. I also changed `  ports:
   - "8000:8000"`  @AlexHall please post an answer so i can accept it, also if you don't mind explaining briefly how the who Guincorn master and workers work then since that's what i was confused on.

Comment: @AlexHall if you don't make an answer by tomorrow im going to write my own. i hate leaving it unanswered and unexplained. I wont accept one for like a week however so you can still collect your acceptance points within a week.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`app.run()` and `gunicorn` are two ways to run a webserver. The first is the Flask development server, and it's useful for development but shouldn't be deployed in production. You shouldn't run both at the same time.

`gunicorn` should be pointed to the `app` object so that it can import it and use it to run the webserver itself. That's all it needs.

Comment: Why does flask have a 'production` vs. 'development` setting if flask apps aren't supposed to be deployed in prod?  Is the idea that the prod setting is to be used in concert with `gunicorn`?

Comment: Adam, flask has got an inbuilt server meant to be used for testing purposes only. Think of it like a development purpose server. Within this server there are 2 modes - this is what you are referring to as production vs development. Production means that stackttrace is not shown during errors, any changes made in code requires reload for it to be visible in browser. Where as development mode means stackttrace is shown during errors and reload is automatic. Flask server (prod/dev mode) is not recommended when you deploy the app into production as it doesn't scale. So use something like gunicorn.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of `CMD [ "gunicorn", "-b", ":8000", "run" ]`

Do `CMD ["gunicorn", "app:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`

You can see that instead of the telling the gunicorn process to `run` you instead tell the process where to **look**.  The application that you want gunicorn to serve is `app`.  You can also add more options to the gunicorn command such as `reload`, the number of workers, timeout, log-levels, etc...

To expand on Alex Hall's answer, you don't want to run a Flask server on production, because the ability to scale is very limited. According to the Flask docs, the mention that:

> Flask’s built-in server is not suitable for production as it doesn’t
>   scale well and by default serves only one request at a time

Comment: There's a comma missing in the 'right' command and stackoverflow won't let me edit less than 6 characters. Just saying